# How do I assign an INI section to a record in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm sorry I'm not being clear...lets try again

I have a record type :

```
MyRecord = Record
   Name: string;
   Age: integer;
   Height: integer;
   several more fields....
```

and an INI file with:

```
[PEOPLE]
Name=Maxine
Age=30
maybe one or two other key/value pairs
```

All I want to do is load the record with the data from the INI file.

I have the data from the INI in a TStringList I want to be able to loop through the TStringList and assign/update only the Record Fields with key value pairs in the TStringList.

Charles

Comment: and are all of those records in the INI file same ? If yes then you should consider to use typed file or such kind of a database depending on the row count. It doesn't look like a good job for INI file.

Comment: @daemon - There is one Section in INI not a set.  The section can contain values for one, many or all of the record fields

Answer (score 6):

So you have an INI file with the content

```
[PEOPLE]
Name=Maxine
Age=30
```

and want to load it into a record defined by

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Name: string;
    Age: integer;
  end;
```

? That is very easy. Just add `IniFiles` to the `uses` clause of your unit, and then do

```
var
  MyRecord: TMyRecord;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TIniFile.Create(FileName) do
    try
      MyRecord.Name := ReadString('PEOPLE', 'Name', '');
      MyRecord.Age := ReadInteger('PEOPLE', 'Age', 0);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Of course, the `MyRecord` variable need not be a global variable. It can also be a local variable or a field in a class. But that all depends on your exact situation, naturally.

**A Simple Generalisation**

A slightly more interesting situation is if your INI files contains several people, like

```
[PERSON1]
Name=Andreas
Age=23

[PERSON2]
Name=David
Age=40

[PERSON3]
Name=Marjan
Age=49

...
```

and you want to load it into an array of `TMyRecord` records, then you can do

```
var
  Records: array of TMyRecord;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sections: TStringList;
  i: TIniFile;
begin
  with TIniFile.Create(FileName) do
    try
      Sections := TStringList.Create;
      try
        ReadSections(Sections);
        SetLength(Records, Sections.Count);
        for i := 0 to Sections.Count - 1 do
        begin
          Records[i].Name := ReadString(Sections[i], 'Name', '');
          Records[i].Age := ReadInteger(Sections[i], 'Age', 0);
        end;
      finally
        Sections.Free;
      end;

    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: @David: You don't need to say it -- I know. The thing is that I don't know if the `TMemIniFile` is available in Delphi 7, which is the version used by the OP.

Comment: @andreas wow, pre-emptive comments now! TMemIniFile fine on D7, was there on D6 for sure and even earlier I bet.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want.  I guess I should have made it more clear that the INI section has several entries and I already have the data in a TStrigList.  Ist there a way to assign the record values from a Tstringlist that has the INI section data?

Comment: @Charles You are looking for `TMemIniFile.SetStrings()`. Or perhaps even avoiding INI files altogther and using `TStringList.Values[]` if you can process the sections yourself. But this is kind of trivial to process by hand without having to fire up extra object instances just to split a couple of Name=Value pairs.

Comment: @Andreas P.S. I like your example data!!

Comment: @Andreas: Me too like your example data. Made me smile!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the INI section in a string list you can just use the `Values[]` property:

**String list contents**

```
Name=Maxine
Age=30
```

**Code to read into record**

```
MyRecord.Name := StringList.Values['Name']
MyRecord.Age = StrToInt(StringList.Values['Age'])
```

Naturally you would want to handle errors one way or another, but this the the basic idea.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I guess I'm not clear on what I want/need. The TStringlist is derived from a TIniFile.ReadSectionValues and the values in the INI might not include all of the records fields or may include fiels not part of the record. I want to use the resultant TStringsList I have from the INI file read to update the record.  Inotherwords...if INI contains "NAME=FRED" I want to update record with "FRED" if it dosn't don't worry about it.  I want to say MyRecord.TStringlist.name := TStringListValues[Name]; Is something like this possible?

Comment: @Charles I can't make sense of what you are asking. Sorry.

Comment: I have a record with fields I want to update with data I have read into a TStringList (MyStrLst) from an TIniFile.ReadSectionValues call.  String list has Name=Value pairs in it I'd like to do something like MyRecord.[Name  from MyStrLst] := [Value from MyStrLst]

Comment: that's not what the question says. It's too hard to fix this go comments. Please edit your question to clarify.